# Firebase Database in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am building an app in which the user can upload photos stored as locally in device on clicking image button. I am using firebase storage to store photos in a folder. When I click on the image picker button it opens up my gallery to select photos, but when I select a photo it never gets showed in the app neither in firebase console storage. Here is my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mMessagesDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
        mFirebaseStorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mChatPhotoStorageReference=mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("chat_photos");
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig=FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
        // Initialize references to views
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
       final  List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, friendlyMessages);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
        mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
                Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"complete action using"),RC_PHOTO_PICKER);

            }
        });

        // Enable Send button when there's text to send
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Send messages on click

                // Clear input box

                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage=new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(),mUsername,null);
                mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

        mAuthStateListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user!=null)
                {
                   onSignedInInitialize(user.getDisplayName());

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You are signed in to friendly chat app",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
               else
                {onSignedOutCleanup();
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setAvailableProviders(
                                            Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()
                                                    ))
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings=new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build();
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings);
        Map<String,Object> defaultConfigMap=new HashMap<>();
        defaultConfigMap.put(FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_kEY,DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT);
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultConfigMap);
        fetchConfig();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RC_SIGN_IN)
        {
         if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
         {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Signed In",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
         else if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
         {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign IN Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          finish();
         }
        }
        else if(resultCode==RC_PHOTO_PICKER&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri=data.getData();
            StorageReference photoRef=mChatPhotoStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage=new FriendlyMessage(null,mUsername,downloadUrl.toString());
                    mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.sign_out_menu:
                AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
            return true;
            default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);}
    }
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
            mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }
      detachDatabaseReadListener();
      mMessageAdapter.clear();
    }
    public void onResume()
    {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
    private void onSignedInInitialize(String username)
    {
      mUsername=username;
       attachDatabaseReadListener();

    }
    private void onSignedOutCleanup()
    {
      mUsername=ANONYMOUS;
      mMessageAdapter.clear();
      detachDatabaseReadListener();
    }
    private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener == null) {
            mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
                    mMessageAdapter.add(friendlyMessage);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };
            mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }
    }
         private void detachDatabaseReadListener()
         {
             if(mChildEventListener!=null)
             {
         mMessagesDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
             mChildEventListener=null;
         }}
    private void fetchConfig()
    {
        long cacheExpiration=3600;
        if(mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled())
        {
        cacheExpiration=0;
        }
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
          .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
              mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
              applyRetrievedLengthLimit();
              }
          })
          .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
              Log.w(TAG,"Error fetching code",e);
              applyRetrievedLengthLimit();
              }
          });
    }
    private void applyRetrievedLengthLimit() {
        Long friendly_msg_length = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong(FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_kEY);
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
                new InputFilter.LengthFilter(friendly_msg_length.intValue())
        });
        Log.d(TAG,FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_kEY + "=" +friendly_msg_length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the log for error ?

Comment: It is showing me no error. And when I click on the photo the user gets back to the app automatically.

Comment: have you implemented the necessary permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes I have used get data permission in manifest file